On the proof of Invariance of Dimension in Rotman's Algebraic Topology book
Below is a proof of Invariance of Dimension in Rotman's book:

I do not understand why we can always find such $\tau$ in the 5th line of the proof. The major problem is that $\tau^{\circ}$ may not be open in the space $\left\lvert L \right\rvert$ for arbitrary $\tau \in K$. (A sufficient condition would be that $\tau$ has the same dimension as $L$, but clearly the author does not intend to appeal to that here. Indeed there are cases when $f(\sigma^{\circ})$ intersects $L$ at a simplex whose dimension is not maximum but is open in $\left\lvert L \right\rvert$ anyway, consider the case when $L$ is a triangle followed by a dangling edge) There is a explanation following this line: "for the stars of vertices form an open cover". I don't quite follow why this would lead to the existence of $\tau$. It is true that we can find $st(p)$ such that $st(p) \cap f(\sigma^{\circ})$ is a nonempty open subset in $\left\lvert L \right\rvert$, but how can I further find $\tau$ from $st(p)$?

The idea is that the interior of $\tau$ is some star, and $\tau$ itself is just its closure. Because stars form an open cover of the simplicial complex $-$as the author points out within the proof$-$, the intersection of $f(\sigmaº)$ with at least one of those has to be open $-$for it would be the intersection of two open sets$-$ and nonempty $-$because stars form a covering$-$.
I hope this comments will clarify the situation for you.

Hi, thanks for the reply. Do you mean $\tau = st(p)$ for some $p \in Vert(L)$? I think there is counterexample of this: For example if $f(\sigma^{\circ})$ is contained in a triangle $\tau$, and each vertex of the triangle is connected to other triangles, then the only simplex intersecting $f(\sigma^{\circ})$ would be $\tau$, but $\tau$ is not $st(p)$ for any $p$

No, $\tauº$ is actually $\text{st}(p)$ for some $p$, not $\tau$.

Thanks for the clarification. But the problem is that $\tau^{\circ} = st(p)$ may not hold for any $p$, in the example I gave?

But stars actually form an open covering of $|L|$, so there will exist some star that cuts $f(\sigma°)$.

Sorry, I must miss something here. We want to find a simplex $\tau$, not a star, right? Sure there is a star that cut $f(\sigma^{\circ})$, but that does not directly say that there is a simplex $\tau$ such that $\tau^{\circ}$ is open and cuts $f(\sigma^{\circ})$.
